# How to access values from previous and next element in sorted xsl:for-each loop

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am using a xsl:for-each loop to sort elements according to their @id-attribute. I need to get the @id-attributes of the previous and next element in the loop.

I've been trying around with the preceding-sibling:: and following-sibling axis, to no avail. I also tried

```
<xsl:variable name="current_pos" select="position()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="(//chapter)[($current_pos - 1)]/id>
```

but this returns the attribute values of the unsorted data.

Sample XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <chapter id="t19"/>
    <chapter id="a23"/>
    <chapter id="c-0"/>
    <chapter id="d42"/>
    <chapter id="c-1"/>
</root>
```

Sample XSLT style sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:for-each select="chapter">
            <xsl:sort select="@id"/>
            <xsl:variable name="current_id" select="@id"/>
            Chapter id: <xsl:value-of select="$current_id"/>
            Sorted position: <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            Sorted predecessor chapter id: ? <!-- no idea but most important -->
            Sorted follower chapter id: ? <!-- no idea but most important -->
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I would need:

```
Chapter id: a23
Sorted position: 1
Sorted predecessor chapter id: none 
Sorted follower chapter id: c-0

Chapter id: c-0
Sorted position: 2
Sorted predecessor chapter id: a23 
Sorted follower chapter id: c-1     

Chapter id: c-1
Sorted position: 3
Sorted predecessor chapter id: c-0 
Sorted follower chapter id: d42

Chapter id: d42
Sorted position: 4
Sorted predecessor chapter id: c-1 
Sorted follower chapter id: t19

Chapter id: t19
Sorted position: 5
Sorted predecessor chapter id: d42 
Sorted follower chapter id: none
```

Comment: Well, first sort, then select the items from the sorted sequence, as you have shown `version="3.0"` and if higher-order functions are supported you can use `sort(chapter, (), function($c) { $c/@id })` to have sorted sequence or even `sort(chapter/@id/data())` to have a sorted string sequence. Outputting all the values could be done elegantly in XQuery with a `tumbling window` clause and the `start` and `end` clause storing the values you are interested in: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the previous and/or following elements in a `xsl:for-each` loop, because strictly speaking `xsl:for-each` is not a loop, but a mapping construct.

What you could do as save the results of the sort in a variable, like so....

```
<xsl:variable name="chapters" as="element()*">
     <xsl:perform-sort select="chapter">
        <xsl:sort select="@id"/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:variable>
```

You could then use `xsl:for-each` on this, and access the previous and next values in the `chapters` variable itself.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$chapters[position() = $current_pos - 1]/@id" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:variable name="chapters" as="element()*">
            <xsl:perform-sort select="chapter">
                <xsl:sort select="@id"/>
            </xsl:perform-sort>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="$chapters">
            <xsl:variable name="current_id" select="@id"/>
            <xsl:variable name="current_pos" select="position()"/>
            Chapter id: <xsl:value-of select="$current_id"/>
            Sorted position: <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            Sorted predecessor chapter id: <xsl:value-of select="$chapters[position() = $current_pos - 1]/@id" />
            Sorted follower chapter id: ? <xsl:value-of select="$chapters[position() = $current_pos + 1]/@id" />
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```